# Why does not my for loop work?

Tags: c++, for-loop, control-flow

The code is as below. I want it to exit the loop when you type `-1`. Or I would like to find a better solution if there is one.

```
if (aa == "hours") {
    std::cout << "Please enter hours below: (Type -1 to stop)" << std::endl;
    for(x; x > -1; x++) {
        std::cin >> hours[x];
        std::cout << hours[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question what is the behaviour you are seeing and why that isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple [break](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break).

```
if (aa == "hours") 
{
    int temp;
    std::cout << "Please enter hours below: (Type -1 to stop)" << std::endl;
    for(int x; x > -1; x++) {

        // Store input in temp
        std::cin >> temp;

        // Check if temp is -1
        if (temp == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        // This code is only executed if temp is not -1
        hours[x] = temp;
        std::cout << hours[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i dont want my program to exit just jump back onto main so to speak.

Comment: @midcore All `break` does is stop the loop. Your program won't exit if there is code after it.